# I am trying to use a bottom sheet modal in flutter conditionally only when users are not subscribed but it's giving me errors

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, modal-dialog

**Problem:** I have a flutter application that after loging in, i want to show a bottom sheet modal popup only when users of the app is not subscribed and restricts them from using the app and is clickable to take them straight to the subscription widget/page.

but i get an error saying "The argument type "Future" can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Widget'

**Solution i tried:**

1. I tried removing the Future and Async function i passed in the FloatingModal Class but it still gives same errors on runtime
2. i converted my stateless widget 'Dashboard' to stateful to see if it does the trick but it didn't work.
3. If this approach is completely wrong, what better approach would you recommend for me for the usecase/problem

Please note i am using the modal_bottom_sheet flutter package by Jaimeblasco. This app is also using a backend in laravel.

The 3 widget actively responsible are `dashboard.dart` `subscription_notice.dart` and `floating_modal.dart` which i'll provide the code snippets.

Please i'll really need help as it's a project i'm working on at this time. Thank you :)

```html
class Dashboard extends StatelessWidget {
  const Dashboard({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    HomeController homeController = Get.find();
    ServicesController servicesController = Get.find();
    VerificationController verificationController = Get.find();
    PlayersController playersController = Get.find();
    var user =
        UserModel.fromJson(jsonDecode(homeController.userData.value)).user!;
        
        Widget content(context) {
      return Obx(() => Column(
            children: [
              Expanded(
                child: ListView(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                        top: 40, left: 20, right: 20, bottom: 20),
                    children: [
                      Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                        children: [
                          Text(
                              AppLocalizations.of(context)!.welcome +
                                  " ${user.firstName}",
                              style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20)),
                              
                              if (servicesController.subscription.isEmpty &&
                          !servicesController.loading &&
                          user.userType != "club_official")
                          FloatingModal(child: showFloatingModalBottomSheet(context: context, builder: (context) => const SubscriptionNotice())),
                          ]);
                           ),
              const HorizontalAdvertBanner()
            ],
          ));
    }
```

```html
class SubscriptionNotice extends StatelessWidget {
  const SubscriptionNotice({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    ServicesController servicesController = Get.find();
    var user =
        UserModel.fromJson(jsonDecode(servicesController.userData.value)).user!;

    return Material(
      child: SafeArea(
        top: false,
        child: Column(
          children: [
            const SizedBox(
              height: 20,
            ),
            CardItem(
                icon: SvgPicture.asset("assets/images/warning_icon.svg"),
                content: RichText(
                  text: TextSpan(
                      children: user.userType == "player"
                          ? [
                              TextSpan(
                                  text:
                                      "you need to subscribe to a plan. Click on this ",
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 14,
                                      color: Get.isDarkMode
                                          ? AppColors.textLigth
                                          : AppColors.textDark,
                                      fontFamily: "Avenir")),
                              const TextSpan(
                                  text: "link",
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      color: Color(0xffFF9432),
                                      fontSize: 14,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                                      fontFamily: "Avenir")),
                              TextSpan(
                                  text: " and subscribe now",
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 14,
                                      color: Get.isDarkMode
                                          ? AppColors.textLigth
                                          : AppColors.textDark,
                                      fontFamily: "Avenir"))
                            ]
                          : [
                              TextSpan(
                                  text:
                                      " you need to subscribe.  Click on this",
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 14,
                                      color: Get.isDarkMode
                                          ? AppColors.textLigth
                                          : AppColors.textDark,
                                      fontFamily: "Avenir")),
                              const TextSpan(
                                  text: " link",
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      color: Color(0xffFF9432),
                                      fontSize: 14,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                                      fontFamily: "Avenir")),
                              TextSpan(
                                  text: ", and subscribe",
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 14,
                                      color: Get.isDarkMode
                                          ? AppColors.textLigth
                                          : AppColors.textDark,
                                      fontFamily: "Avenir"))
                            ]),
                ),
                onPressed: () {
                  TabRouting().pushScreen(context, const Services());
                }),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

```html
class FloatingModal extends StatelessWidget {
  final Widget child;
  final Color? backgroundColor;

  const FloatingModal({Key? key, required this.child, this.backgroundColor})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
        child: Material(
          color: backgroundColor,
          clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
          child: child,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

Future<T> showFloatingModalBottomSheet<T>({
  required BuildContext context,
  required WidgetBuilder builder,
  Color? backgroundColor,
}) async {
  final result = await showCustomModalBottomSheet(
      context: context,
      builder: builder,
      containerWidget: (_, animation, child) => FloatingModal(
            child: child,
          ),
      expand: false);

  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your `FloatingModal` it seeks a widget as a child. But `showFloatingModalBottomSheet` is a future method.

You can use a tappable widget and on it tap event use this method.

```dart
 FloatingModal(
    child: ElevatedButton(
  onPressed: () async {
     showFloatingModalBottomSheet(context: context, builder: (context) => const SubscriptionNotice());
  },
  child: Text("showX"),
  ),
)
```

To show dialog directly after widget build on `StatelessWidget`

```dart
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((timeStamp) async {
      //condition if needed 
await showFloatingModalBottomSheet(context: context, builder: (context) => const SubscriptionNotice());
    });
```

Comment: use `await` if needed on `await showFloatingModa.....`

Comment: this works thank you! but the idea wasn't to show a button, the idea was to let the modal popup immediately after logging in if the condition is met... i don't want to show a button at all, but a popup immediately after the user logs in and the condition stated is being met. is there a way to go around this?

again thank you!

Comment: You can use `addPostFrameCallback` inside build method.

Comment: This works!!!
I had to add it in my second widget as : ```Widget showPlayerSwitcher() {
      WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((timeStamp) async {
        //condition if needed
        if (servicesController.subscription.isEmpty &&
            !servicesController.loading &&
            user.userType != "club_official") {
          await showFloatingModalBottomSheet(
              context: context,
              builder: (context) => const SubscriptionNotice());
        }
      });```
THANK YOU!

Comment: Glad to help, Also use this inside initState for statefullWidget

Comment: if you don't mind sir, how do i restrict it from closing to restrict users from using the app and even after they navigate to the subscription page, how do i make it persistent?

Do i have to call it on the build method of every widget now?

Comment: You can try adding `isDismissible: false` on `showModalBottomSheet`

Comment: i requested to connect on linkedIn, we could be friends if you don't mind as i continue my flutter developer journey :)